# Algorithm to compute the convex hull of a set of $m$ possibly intersecting convex polygons in the plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hulls

I am trying to find an algorithm to compute the convex hull of a set of $m$ possibly intersecting convex polygons in the plane, with a total of $n$ vertices. Let $h$ denote the number of vertices on the boundary of the
desired convex hull. The algorithm should run in $\mathcal O(mh+n)$ time

Comment: how are the polygons given?

Comment: as a list of vertices ordered clock-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer; just some remarks.

This paper is directly on your topic, but unfortunately I cannot access it:

> Chen, H., and J. Rokne. "The convex hull of a set of convex polygons." *International Journal of Computer Mathematics* **42**, no. 3-4 (1992): 163-172.

You probably know that merging $m{=}2$ convex polygons can be accomplished 
in linear time, $O(n)$.
And there is the [Kirkpatrick–Seidel output-size sensitive algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkpatrick%E2%80%93Seidel_algorithm) that achieves $O(n \log h)$.